# Calling a Gradle Custom Task at any compile execution

Tags: plugins, gradle

Hi am writing a Gradle custom plugin.

1) I am creating a Task in my plugin and i want that task to be called when any of compile task is called.

say user may call compileJava, compileJava etc

OR
2) Can i call when user invokes gradle war  task. instead of gradle warMyFiles

I want to invoke my plugin taks on any of this these compile task

i normally set the task into my plugin like this

...
CompileMyFilesTask compileMyFiles = project.tasks.add(COMPILE_MYFILES_TASK_NAME, CompileMyFilesTask.class)
        compileMyFiles.dependsOn(WarPlugin.WAR_TASK_NAME)   // or JavaPlugin.COMPILE_...
        compileMyFiles.description = "Compile MyFiles"
        compileMyFiles.group = "MyFiles"
...

Comment: It might help if you can tell us what the goal of your plug-in is - what will it do? You want your task to wrap existing tasks or it should be a dependency of all tasks?

Comment: Actually its compiles some files. As a JVM language support user may or may not have java or scala or groovy applied to his build. So i dont wayto say JavaPlugin_Compiler... to restrict my plugin work only when java been added. User may only use Scala so i feel my plugin may not work if java is not added and only scala is been added or groovy.

Comment: Also later once that done i need to add it into the war also.

Comment: You're not giving us enough information - 'compiles some files', which language?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you have a look at gradle source code for internal plug-ins, like the Java plugin (can be found at `GRADLE_HOME/src/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin.java`)

Here's an idea borrowed from there. This code makes all compile tasks in the project depend on your custom task:

```
import org.gradle.api.Task;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.AbstractCompile;

...

final Task yourCustomTask = ...

project.getTasks().withType(AbstractCompile.class, new Action<Task>(){
  @Override
  public void execute(Task compileTask){
    compileTask.dependsOn(yourCustomeTask);
  }
});
```

Note: if your custom task is also of type `AbstractCompile` you'll need to exclude it in the loop to avoid cyclic dependencies.

For the war task your current approach seems good.

Comment: Using a conventional loop isn't safe because it won't pick up tasks added after the plugin has been applied. Instead, you have to use `project.tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) { ... }`. There is also a Java version of `withType` that accepts an `Action` instead of a `Closure`.

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect your point. Haven't actually tried compiling it but should be about right.